# Deny AWS IAM User access to specific elastic beanstalk environments

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam, aws-devops

I have a problem with restricting the access to AWS Elastic Beanstalk to specific environments.
The goal is to create a policy that allows an IAM user to access the complete elastic beanstalk service (including creating new apps and environments), but completely deny access to the production environment in a specific app.

What I've tried is this (mainly copied from [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-iam-permissions/)), but it doesn't seem to work apparently - the user just with this policy attached gets access to all of AWS like the root user:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticbeanstalk:UpdateApplicationVersion",
                "elasticbeanstalk:CreateApplicationVersion",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DeleteApplicationVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "elasticbeanstalk:InApplication": [
                        "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:<region>:<account id>:environment/<app name>/<environment name>"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeAccountAttributes",
                "elasticbeanstalk:AbortEnvironmentUpdate",
                "elasticbeanstalk:TerminateEnvironment",
                "rds:*",
                "elasticbeanstalk:ValidateConfigurationSettings",
                "elasticbeanstalk:CheckDNSAvailability",
                "autoscaling:*",
                "elasticbeanstalk:RequestEnvironmentInfo",
                "elasticbeanstalk:RebuildEnvironment",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeInstancesHealth",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironmentHealth",
                "sns:*",
                "elasticbeanstalk:RestartAppServer",
                "s3:*",
                "cloudformation:*",
                "elasticloadbalancing:*",
                "elasticbeanstalk:CreateStorageLocation",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEnvironmentManagedActions",
                "elasticbeanstalk:SwapEnvironmentCNAMEs",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeConfigurationOptions",
                "elasticbeanstalk:ApplyEnvironmentManagedAction",
                "cloudwatch:*",
                "elasticbeanstalk:CreateEnvironment",
                "elasticbeanstalk:List*",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DeleteEnvironmentConfiguration",
                "elasticbeanstalk:UpdateEnvironment",
                "ec2:*",
                "elasticbeanstalk:RetrieveEnvironmentInfo",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeConfigurationSettings",
                "sqs:*",
                "dynamodb:CreateTable",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTable"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role",
                "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role",
                "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:instance-profile/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEvents",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeApplications",
                "elasticbeanstalk:AddTags",
                "elasticbeanstalk:ListPlatformVersions"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "elasticbeanstalk:InApplication": [
                        "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:<region>:<account id>:environment/<app name>/<environment name>"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticbeanstalk:AddTags",
                "elasticbeanstalk:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:*::platform/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:*:*:environment/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:*:*:application/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:*::solutionstack/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:*:*:applicationversion/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:*:*:configurationtemplate/*/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "elasticbeanstalk:InApplication": [
                        "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:<region>:<account id>:environment/<app name>/<environment name>"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The page your're referring is for restricting specific EB with *applications* not for envs.

[This doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.policies.actions.html) says about condition keys for Elastic Beanstalk actions,

> `InApplication`:
>
> Specifies the application that contains the resource
> that the action operates on.
>
> `FromEnvironment`:
>
> Specifies an environment as a dependency or a constraint on an input
> parameter.

... you can see the explanations and examples more.

The bottom line is that changing `"elasticbeanstalk:InApplication"` to `"elasticbeanstalk:FromEnvironment"` would work.